# Updating a parent component when child component variable is changed

Tags: angular, angular2-components

For example I have a variable called totalQuantity that came from a service.

I have a child component that initializes that variable **ONLY** if a user has logged in.

This is the child component.

```
import { Component, OnInit, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

import { CartService } from '../cart';

@Component({
    selector: 'landing',
    templateUrl: './landing.component.html'
})

export class LandingComponent implements OnInit{
    @Output() homeChanged = new EventEmitter;

    constructor(private _cartService: CartService){}

    ngOnInit(){
        this._cartService.getCartItems(localStorage.getItem('currentUserId'))
            .subscribe((cart) => {
                this.homeChanged.emit(this._cartService.totalQuantity);
                console.log(this._cartService.totalQuantity);
            },
            err => console.log(err));
    }
}
```

As you can see, I have an @Output variable called homeChanged and will emit the totalQuantity when the child component initializes. I need to display it in my parent component **IF ONLY** the user is logged in because that's the only time *Cart* on navbar will show.

This is my parent component.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

import { loginStatusChanged } from './auth.guard';
import { CartService } from './cart';
import { UserService } from './user';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
  title = 'app works!';

  loginStatus: boolean;

  constructor(private _cartService: CartService, private _userService: UserService, private _router: Router){}

  onLogout(){
    this._userService.logout();
    loginStatusChanged.next(false);
    this._router.navigate(['/login']);
  }

  ngOnInit(){
    this.onLogout();
    loginStatusChanged.subscribe(status => this.loginStatus = status);
  }
}
```

Parent component HTML where I will put the `totalQuantity`

```
<ul class="navigation">
  <li class="logo"><img src="assets/images/nav_logo.png"></li>
  <li><a routerLink="/home" routerLinkActive="active">Home</a></li>
  <li><a routerLink="/mainproducts" routerLinkActive="active">Products</a></li>
  <li *ngIf="loginStatus"><a href="http://localhost:3000">Designer</a></li>
  <li *ngIf="loginStatus"><a routerLink="/cart" routerLinkActive="active">Cart({{totalQuantity}})</a></li>
  <li *ngIf="!loginStatus"><a routerLink="/login" routerLinkActive="active">Login</a></li>
  <li *ngIf="loginStatus" class="dropdown"><a (click)="onLogout()">Logout</a></li>

</ul>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Can anyone help me on displaying the totalQuantity on my navbar beside the cart?

Comment: where are you setting you property I dont see its set in AppComponent ?

Comment: Where do you use the landing component? You need something like `<landing (homeChanged)="totalQuantity = $event"></landing>`

Comment: none. I am using a router outlet to navigate. Is there any way to update the Cart?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Subjects, like so:

In your parent:

```
public static returned: Subject<any> = new Subject();
```

and in your parent constructor you subscribe to changes in child, like so:

```
  AppComponent.returned.subscribe(res => {
     console.log('change happened!');
     console.log(res) // you have your passed value here
  });
```

And in your childcomponent, where you need parent updated add this, and as parameter what you want, here we just pass a string.

```
AppComponent.returned.next('test'); // pass whatever you need
```

EDIT: Output only works in case your child component is NOT behind a different route. So in your case you cannot use Output.

Answer (score 0):

here is how you can update parent component from child .

```
        @Component({
          selector: 'child-selector',
          template: 'child.component.html'
        })
        export class ChildComponent {  
          @output() notify: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>();

          onClick() {
            this.notify.emit('Click from nested component');
          }
        }




        /* parent.conponent.html */
        <div>  
          <h1>I'm a container component</h1>
          <child-selector (notify)='onNotify($event)></child-selector>
        </div>  




        @Component({
          selector: 'parent-selector',
          template: 'parent.component.html',
          directives: [ChildComponent]
        })
        export class ParentComponent {  
          onNotify(message:string):void {
            alert(message);
          }
        }
```

Comment: I am using a router outlet to navigate so i don't have the selector of the child component.

Comment: ok but you have cartService injected in Appcomponent so on OnIt you can  call this service and update totalItem property after user is logedin . just a guess worth to try

Comment: done that but the problem is, app component will initialize when the app started even if the user is not logged in. if there is any way to re initialize or update the UI of the app component AFTER the user is logged in that would be very helpful

Comment: sorry if I understand correctly app component will initialize when the app started even if the user is not logged in . But user must  log in somewhere what we need to do it when user login at that time we need to call cartservice  . I think if you have emitter in login service which will update when user logged in then you can use that in app component .

Comment: my problem is that I have no selector because I am using router outlet. I do not know where to put if there is no child selector in parent component. As stated on my code, app.component only consist of my navbar and a router outlet.